# Service works in Tomcat doesn´t work on Servicemix

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, service, apache-servicemix

I´ve deployed a service into Tomcat 6 and into Servicemix 4.3

I´ve used soapUI 4 to send a request to the servers, from tomcat i get an answer, from servicemix i don´t. Both requests are differente Tomcat port 8080, servicemix port 8181.

The service is SOAP web-service in a .war file.
Has anyone done this type of migration? Do i need libraries in servicemix from tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is likely your packaging/installation of your war and/or missing OSGi bundles...

see this [blog post](http://cmoulliard.blogspot.com/2009/03/servicemix-4-as-web-application-server.html) for info on using Servicemix as a web server...

essentially something like this...

```
osgi:install -s war:file:/tmp/sample.war?Webapp-Context=sample
```

then you should be able to go to http://localhost:8080/sample

also, [this guide](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3/esb_deploy_osgi/UrlHandlers-War.html) should help explain the OSGi war commands a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm confused.

Tomcat is a servlet/JSP engine, built to deploy servlets, JSPs and web services (given the proper library support).

ServiceMix is an ESB that can do routing to servlets, transforming of messages, guarantee delivery, workflow, and other services.  It's supposed to decouple producers of messages from consumers.

I don't see ServiceMix as an alternative deployment platform for servlets and JSPs.  I see them as complementary, not one replacing the other.

Comment: Then you are saying that i should use servicemix to access the service i have running on Tomcat? Because there are exmples of webservices running in servicemix like this one http://servicemix.apache.org/14-beginner-running-the-wsdl-first-example.html